# Bounding Box Collision On Certain Sides

Tags: c#, xna

I have a player sprite and a spikes sprite.  The spikes are facing down and about at head level with the player.  I have set it so that if the right side of the player's rectangle goes into the spikes's rectangle, it stops moving.  However, I want to set it up like this-

```
if (playerRect.Right == spikesRect.Left - 1)
{
    speedRight = 0;
}
```

However, this does not work.  The player can continue to go past it.  The only way I can get it to work is if I do this-

```
if (playerRect.Right > spikesRect.Left)
{
    speedRight = 0;
}
```

To clarify, the spikesRect.Left value is 350.  I want it so that if playerRect.Right is equal to 349, to stop moving to the right.  Thanks for any help, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a basic collision, use:

```
if(playerRect.Intersects(spikesRect))
{
//handle collision
}
```

I recommend having a velocity and a direction variable instead of different variables for different direction's speeds, it means that you only have to change one variable if you want your character to change speed or direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is caused by some changes you make to `speedRight` or to `playerRect` somewhere in your game. So if you're using VisualStudio just set a breakpoint and check the `speedRight` and `playerRect` values.

Although there are a few changes you should make to your game. Firstly you should create a public field into the `Player` class of type `Texture` as for the `Spike` class, then create another field of type `Vector2` which indicates the speed and the direction :

```
public class Player{
    public Vector2 DirectionSpeed;
    public Texture2D Texture;
    //...

    public Player(){
        //initialize your fields
    }
}
```

Then you can handle the collision by using the method [`Intersects()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.aspx):

```
if(player.Texture.Bounds.Intersects(spike.Bounds)){
    player.DirectionSpeed = Vector.Zero;
}
```

If you are trying to handle the collisions with more than one object of type `Spike`, you have to create a `List<Spike>` and then iterate with a cicle the entire list:

```
foreach(Spike s in listSpikes){
    if(player.Texture.Bounds.Intersects(s.Bounds)){
        player.DirectionSpeed = Vector.Zero;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Moreover if `speedRight` doesn't equal 1 or a submultiple of `spikesRect.Left - 1` it's obvious that by increasing the position with it `playerRect.Right` exceeds `spikesRect.Left - 1`. A solution could be:

```
if (playerRect.Right > spikesRect.Left - 1)
{
    playerRect.Location = spikesRect.Left - playerRect.Width - 1;
    speedRight = 0;
}
```

Comment: This would give him the same problem he had before. His problem was that the pictures of the player and the spike would overlap because the condition is only considered after the player has penetrated the spike.

Comment: @TheUnrealMegashark Please check the edited part of my answer, it should work for you.

Comment: Yup that's basically a more processor costly implementation of what i put on my answer. Wouldn't make a difference for just a couple spikes but with thousands of spikes little things like extra subtractions can make alot of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is is that as your player is moving it is not always going to land on spot 349. as its moving it might move from 348 to 350. therefore it will never trigger when it's 349. What you could however do is.

```
int i = spikesRect.Left - playerRect.Right;
if ( i < 0 )
    playerRect.X += i; //playerRect.X can be replaced by a position variable
```

When it reaches spot 351. 350 - 351 = -1 so since it is less than 0 it will be added to playerRect.X making playerRect.X moved back to where playerRect.Right is 350. That way it won't look as if your player is penetrating the spike.